# UIImage not resizing according to UIImageView size width and height

Tags: swift, uiimageview, storyboard, uiimage, ibinspectable

I am a Swift newbie and I am trying to add an UIImageView on the right of UITextField using Storyboard and @IBInspectable annotation.
However, when I define my UIImageView with specific size and add the UIImage, the UIImage is not resizing according to UIImageView size.

Here's my code:

```
    @IBInspectable var rightImage: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        guard let image = rightImage else {
            return
        }
        rightViewMode = .always
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        rightView = imageView
```

and here's the result on the screen:
[Big big icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gByll.png)

If you can tell me what is wrong with my code, do not hesitate.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to use autolayout, not a frame, to configure the image view.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I added constraints to my UIImageView and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use constraints based on Matt’s suggestion in the comment, and it's working now:

```
let constraints = [
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
]

NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```